# Finding nearest color in RGB?

Tags: colors, rgb

I have to find the nearest color. For example, I have two colors colorA1, colorA2 which are nearly same color. And also I have other color colorB1.
And I need such a method:
Color getNearestColor(colorA1, colorA2, colorB1). This method should give me the colorB2 which is calculated by using the difference of colorA1 and colorA2, then using their distance it should give me colorB2 which has the same distance as in colorA1 and colorA2.
Can you give some ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the nearest colour, you need a definition of "near", so a metric.

In Wikipedia you will find different metrics of [color differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).

Personally I would use the 2*R*R + 4*G*G + 3*B*B. (no need for square roots, you will just compare same metrics). Easy to calculate, you can use just integers (if you use 32 bit integers, you will have no overflow).

Then find which colour has the smallest differences between your target colour.

The other methods are more precise, but in that case "RGB" is not enough. You need to know which colour space are using (probably you are in sRGB).